# If else statement with random choices

Tags: objective-c, if-statement

I´m wondering if it´s possible to create some kind of an or statement inside an if/else statement that randomly chooses from different values -

Like this:

```
if ([white.number floatValue] >= 15.0f) {
             [forcastLabel setText:@"Good!"]; OR STATEMENT - [forcastLabel setText:@"BRILLIANT"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sth like this :)

```
NSInteger randomNumber = arc4random() % 2;

if ([white.number floatValue] >= 15.0f) {
         randomNumber > 0 ? [forcastLabel setText:@"Good!"] : [forcastLabel setText:@"BRILLIANT"];
```

There is many other ways to achieve what you want my is just one of them.

Comment: nice! If I have several labels to set in every random choice. Can I do that aswell? For example set forcastLabel text to Good and forcastLabel2 to Job! and the do colon and next alternative

Comment: You can do this : randomNumber > 0 ?/*action on true*/ : /*action on false*/ for every label (one at a time) or just use another if-statment and do it like: if(randomNumber){ //setting some text for labels } else { //setting other text for labels } btw if it answers your question please mark it as an answer